# Is there way to get which core is used by the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Is there way to get which core is used by the thread?
for example

```
printf("..., Core: %2d\n", coreN);
```

Comment: No. C++ doesn't have a notion of core

Comment: You might need to use an operating system specific function to figure that out.

Comment: The core which is used by the thread can be switched several times during this call to printf unless you specifically configure thread affinity.

Comment: Somebody is bound to mislead by this info, your OS provides no guarantee that it stays executing on that same core.  The printf function itself is already quite likely to cause a context switch.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Linux based systems you can use

```
sched_getcpu()
```

to print the current CPU/core number on which the thread is running

```
cout << "Thread running on Core " << sched_getcpu() <<endl
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not provide a function or anything for achieving this, since there is no notion of core in the language.

You could run a Linux command via a system call to check that out: [How can I see which CPU core a thread is running in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032372/how-can-i-see-which-cpu-core-a-thread-is-running-in)