# Python - Why would multiprocessing code be slower than single threaded?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm using [Python's multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and I was following this [repo's code](https://blog.varunajayasiri.com/ml/ppo_pytorch.html). As you can see based on `main.py` and `terminal` something odd is going on. Based on the documentation and a [tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/a-beginners-guide-to-multi-processing-in-python/) I read. The `time` library should print before the workers finish, because I did not call the `<process object>.join()` function and time is on the main process, but as we can see in terminal it prints `Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.` which comes from `do_some_task` function. Something else weird that is going on is using multiprocessing is much slower than just iteratively calling `do_some_task` function. As we can see in `terminal`. What is going on?

main.py

```
from worker import Worker
from task import do_some_task
import time

tic = time.time()
num_workers = 8

workers = [Worker() for i in range(num_workers)]

for worker in workers:
    worker.child.send(("task", None))

for i, worker in enumerate(workers):
    obs_workers[i] = worker.child.recv()

for worker in workers:
    worker.child.send(("close", None))

toc = time.time()

print(f'Multi time was: {toc-tic}')

tic = time.time()

for i in range(num_workers):
    do_some_task()

toc = time.time()
print(f'Single time: {toc-tic}')
```

worker.py

```
import multiprocessing
from task import do_some_task

def worker_process(remote: multiprocessing.connection.Connection, cfg: dict, seed: int):
    while True:
        cmd, data = remote.recv()
        if cmd == "task":
            do_some_task()
        elif cmd == "close":
            remote.close()
            break
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, cfg, seed) -> None:
        self.child, parent = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process, args=(parent, cfg, seed))
        self.process.start()
```

terminal

```
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Multi time was: 40.21380949020386
Found 8 GPUs for rendering. Using device 0.
Single time: 5.607028484344482
```

Comment: Multiprocessing should only be used when your code is unable to parallelize with threads _specifically_ because it's waiting for the GIL, and where the data that needs to be moved between processes isn't too expensive to deserialize and reserialize. Unless both those things are true, it's completely normal for multiprocessing to make things worse instead of better, because it's incurring extra costs (to move data across process boundaries) for no benefit.

Comment: Moreover, libraries that are able to use GPU assistance are generally able to parallelize _on their own_, so there's no need to use something like multiprocessing on top. When you try to parallelize at two different layers, you just create resource contention and slow things down even more via OS-level task-switching overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if that's the case then is the code in the link I referenced: https://blog.varunajayasiri.com/ml/ppo_pytorch.html not parallelizing anything?

Comment: I didn't claim this was "not parallelizing anything"; what I claimed is that its attempts to parallelize smell counterproductive. And yes, that's also true of the code in the link (though it's much better designed!); if you want PyTorch to parallelize effectively, the approach that's approved and documented upstream is to have multiple CPUs and use [DataParallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html). DataParallel _doesn't_ use multiprocessing, so it doesn't pay all the shipping costs I talked about (unless you use one of its distributed backends).

Comment: That said, I do also agree, reading that this code, that it _isn't_ parallelizing anything -- because you only have one `worker_process` and it runs the jobs it's given one at a time. The answer by @parmicciano shows you how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing multiprocessing here. You just add task in a queue. => They will be executed by a core.
Please use this [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

For instance, this code snippet [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361232/use-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing) allows you to use every cores you have, just edit the worker function with the code that you wants to multiprocess

```
import os
import time
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def worker(n):
    factorial = np.math.factorial(900000)
    # rank = multiprocessing.current_process().name one can also use
    rank = multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0]
    print(f'I am processor {rank}, got n={n}, and finished calculating the factorial.')


cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
input_params_list = range(1, cpu_count+1)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_count)
pool.map(worker, input_params_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Please extend this answer so it's self-contained enough to be usable without needing to follow links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this answer also doesn't account for sending commands