# Python multiprocessing Pool over CPU nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am using a Windows based PC with CPU that has 96 cores (48 in node#1 and 48 in node#2)
Am running a Python script using the `multiprocessing` module.

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    def mp_main():# main function to be run in parallel....

    mp_ins =.. # iterable inputs to mp_main 
    num_pools = 92
    with Pool(num_pools) as p:
        p.map(mp_main,mp_ins)
```

by inspecting the task manager and resource manager I see that the CPU utilizitation is about 50% where all the cores that belongs to node#1 are close to 100% and vice versa for the cores of node#2.

How can I utilize the cores of node#2 better?

Comment: 0% utilization of node 2 cores?

Comment: should `num_pools` be 96 instead of 92?

Comment: @Anentropic very close to 0%, for 92 cores I also  expect ~100%

Comment: It might mean that the task is not cpu-bound enough (or possibly the parent process can't feed input data fast enough) to push the OS scheduler into using all the cores https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361232/use-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand [Processor Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups).

There are multiple solutions, but I'll mention only one simple solution.
In the terminal(cmd), run two python processes for two nodes, assuming you divided input data for two processes.

```
> start /node 1 python xxx.py process_only_half_of_input
> start /node 2 python xxx.py process_the_other_half_of_input
```