# OpenMP multi-threading not working if OpenMPI set to use one or two MPI processor

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, openmpi, hybrid

I developed a code parallelized in a hybrid way based on OpenMPI + OpenMP. It works as I expect if 'enough' number of MPI processors are given. So far based on tests, I would roughly say 'enough' means more than two MPI processors.

A problem I observe is that if the code is allocated only one or two MPI processors, then the multi-threading via OpenMP does not work as expected, but stuck by 200% CPU usage (i.e., uses only 2-threads), not more. It is very unclear why this happens.

Here is information about running environment;

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS,
gfortran 13.2.0,
openmpi 4.1.5

To provide reporduction of my issue, here is a toy code that replicates the same issue;

```
     program parallel_example
    
        use OMP_LIB

        implicit none

        include 'mpif.h'
    
        integer :: i, j, k, n, ierror, size_Of_Cluster, process_Rank
        real    :: sum, x

        call MPI_INIT(ierror)
        call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_Of_Cluster, ierror)
        call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_Rank, ierror)

        call omp_set_dynamic(.False.)
        call omp_set_num_threads(5) 
 
       !$OMP PARALLEL
           print *, 'hello from thread:', OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM(), &
       &  'of proc=', process_Rank
       !$OMP END PARALLEL

       ! Set the number of iterations
       n = 100000
      
       ! Initialize the sum
       sum = 0.0

       !$omp parallel do collapse(3) default(none) private(i, j, k, x) shared(sum, n)
       do i = 1, n
         do j = 1, n
           do k = 1, n
           !print *, 'hello from thread:', OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM(), i, j, k
             x = 1.0 / (real(i) + real(j) + real(k))
             !$omp atomic
             sum = sum + x
           enddo
         enddo
       end do
       !$omp end parallel do
      
       print *, "The sum is: ", sum

       call MPI_Finalize(ierror)

      end program parallel_example
```

The number of threads per MPI processor is set to 5. So I expect 500% CPU usage of each MPI processor from 'top' command of my ubuntu.

This is compile and execution processes;

```
mpif90 -fopenmp test.F90 -o app.exe
mpirun -np 1 ./app.exe
```

If I use 'mpirun -np 1' or 'mpirun -np 2', the CPU usage is stuck by 200%, no more. But if I give more than 2, for example 'mpirun -np 3', I can finally see 500% CPU usage for each of those three MPI processors.

It is very unclear to me why I cannot get 500% CPU usage with one or two MPI processors. I am pretty sure I am missing something to setup the environment properly, but I really don't know what is wrong. So if anyone has knowledge on this, please consider sharing it with me.

- Update: The answer has been identified - addition of "--map-by node:pe=N" resolved the issue. This means even with one MPI processor, five threads is able to be used. It seems that argument is an OpenMPI convention, but I do not fully understand it yet. But to help with other people who may suffer with similar issues, I hope "--map-by node:pe=N" can resolve them. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: What are your thread affinity settings? Can you change them with `OMP_PROC_BIND=core` or similar? I do not recommmend using `omp_set_num_threads` and I do not recommend using `include "mpif.h"`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried OMP_PROC_BIND=core, but the issue remains the same. Regarding include "mpif.h", my main code uses PETSc to initialize MPI. So I do not have it. For omp_set_num_threads, I wonder which option is recommended to explicitly set the number of desired threads.

Comment: I also tried OMP_PROC_BIND=true / OMP_PROC_BIND=false / OMP_PROC_BIND="spread, spread, close", but the issue remains the same.

Comment: For setting the number of threads use the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS

Comment: If you print out the number of threads spawned in the parallel region containing the loop what does it tell you?

Comment: @IanBush - Thank you for the note. I tried export OMP_NUM_THREADS=5, for example, but the issue is still there. But I'll use OMP_NUM_THREADS to specify the number of threads.

Comment: @IanBush - "hello from thread: " part in the above toy code inside the parallel section tells from zero to four. So there are indeed five threads involved, even with one MPI processor. But in CPU usage from top command, I see only 200%.

Comment: How many CPUs does your machine have (NOT cores)? Is it possible that at low numbers of MPI ranks the threads are being split across multiple CPUs and that affects what top reports?

Comment: No. That is a separate, different parallel region. Different regions can have different numbers of threads. Please tell us how many threads are being used in the region you are asking about, the one with the loops. I think it very unlikely that it is different, but it would be good to check.

Comment: @IanBush - grep "physical id" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u --> gives two (i.e., physical id : 0, physical id : 1). grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo --> gives 96. grep "cpu cores" /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1 --> gives "cpu cores : 24". So there are two physical CPUs, and 24 physical cores for each, and hyperthreading enabled. For the second point, I am not sure how to check this. Any recommendation?

Comment: @IanBush - I actually check that too, and it gives zero to four (i.e., five threads). But I observed that if I print out within the massive parallelized loop, the ideal CPU usage cannot be achieved. But anyway, I checked that five threads are involved for the loop of interest too, while giving only 200% CPU usage.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032372/how-can-i-see-which-cpu-core-a-thread-is-running-in

Comment: @IanBush - This is what I get from ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p `pgrep app.exe` : 
    PID     TID %CPU PSR 
1700288       -  202   - 
      - 1700288 40.7   0
      - 1700289  0.0   0
      - 1700290  0.0   0
      - 1700291 41.1   0
      - 1700292 40.2  48
      - 1700293 40.2   0
      - 1700294 39.9  48

Comment: There are seven entries, but only five of them (i.e., which are assigned as thread I guess) are changing over time if I check it using; watch -tdn0.5 ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p \`pgrep app.exe\`

Comment: Please edit the question to include this new information